# Matplotlib Pylot - Images are being displayed in low resolution (pixel to pixel)

Tags: matplotlib, computer-vision, pytorch, torchvision, dataloader

When I display some samples photos from the dataset I use, the previews of images are displayed in low resolution (they look like very low-resolution photos). How I can I display the images without losing their resolutions?

Here are my `transformations` which are used to move the data to the tensor and apply some transformations using `PyTorch` functions:

```
data_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((50, 50)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                         std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])
```

Then I load the data through `DataLoader`:

```
train_loader = DataLoader(face_train_dataset,
                          batch_size=train_batch_size, shuffle=False,
                          num_workers=4)
```

Finally, I display some previews for the sample photos which are retrieved using the `DataLoader` object:

```
example_data = example_data.cpu()
example_targets = example_targets.cpu()
for i in range(6):
    plt.subplot(2, 3, i + 1)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.imshow(example_data[i][0], cmap='gray', interpolation='none')
    plt.title('{}'.format(folders[example_targets[i]]))

plt.show()
```

p.s. Images are in `tiff` format.

Answer (score 1):

What resolution are you expecting?

One of the transformations you are applying is

> ```
> transforms.Resize((50, 50))
> ```

That is, you are reducing the input images resolution to 50 by 50 pixels. This is the resolution you are getting when you plot the images.

In order to have a more graceful display of the low-res images you might want to consider changing the [interpolation method](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html) of `imshow` to

```py
plt.imshow(example_data[i][0], cmap='gray', interpolation='bicubic')
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that but I do not want them to lose their quality - as I just resize (downscale) them. They currently look like 'pixel to pixel'.

Comment: Thanks but it is very blurry now when I use `bicubic` interpolation as you have suggested.

Comment: @talha06 what are you expecting from a 50x50 image?

Comment: I see where you are coming from but not all 50x50 images are being displayed in that pixel to pixel form.